# Can't re-enable location after disabling it in settings

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

In my app I am requesting permission to access location services. This works perfectly using

```
 @IBAction func enableLocation(sender: AnyObject) {

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if status != .AuthorizedAlways{

        print("button pressed \(status)")

        self.manager.delegate = self
        self.manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    } else {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("locationEnabled", sender: nil)
    }

}


 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        print("Auth Changed")

        switch status {
        case .NotDetermined:
            self.manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            break
        case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:

            self.activityIndicator.hidden = false
            self.activityIndicator.isAnimating()

            performSegueWithIdentifier("locationEnabled", sender: nil)

            break
        case .AuthorizedAlways:

            self.activityIndicator.hidden = false
            self.activityIndicator.isAnimating()

            performSegueWithIdentifier("locationEnabled", sender: nil)

            break
        case .Restricted:
            // restricted by e.g. parental controls. User can't enable Location Services

            break
        case .Denied:


            // user denied your app access to Location Services, but can grant access from Settings.app
            break
        default:
            break
        }

    }
```

However, when I disable location specifically for the app in settings it refuses to re-enable it when the button is pressed. If a user de-activates location in settings can it not be re-enable in the app?

Comment: As the user specifically changed it in setting it will not request the user again for permission. That is why some apps say, please be sure to activate Location setting for this app. You could however take them to the settings app directly from within the app itself making it a lot more pleasant for the user.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification @ErionV. I will navigate them to settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution may not be the prettiest but it solved my problem

First you need to check as standard if location has been accepted. In that check I delay a method to see if the locationManager delegate has been fired through a simple `BOOL`.

```
        let delay = 0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                if(!self.locationApproved){
                    self.openSettings()
                }
        })
```

I put a BOOL in `locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)`

```
locationApproved = true
```

And if the location hasn't been approved (i.e. the locationManger delegate hasn't fired) I run my function to prompt to go to app settings.

```
func openSettings(){

    let uiAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Location not authorised", message: "Looks like you have turned off your location. We need this to show you the closest offers", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    self.presentViewController(uiAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    uiAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to settings", style: .Default, handler: { action in
        let settingsUrl = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
        if let url = settingsUrl {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }))

    uiAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel, handler: { action in
        print("Click of cancel button")
    }))
```